# When nesting layouts in Rails, how do I prevent my application.css file from getting included twice?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, layout, include

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  When nesting layouts, how do I prevent my application.css.scss file from getting included twice?  In my “app/views/layouts/application.html.erb” file I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Runtrax" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Runtrax" %>">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <% if !current_user.nil? %>
    <div id="container">
    <header>
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
      <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
      <%= yield %>
    </main>
    </div>
    <% else %>
      <%= yield %>
    <% end %>

  </body>
</html>
```

And then in my users layout, app/views/layouts/user.html.erb, I have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "countries" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "users" %>

<%= yield %>

<% parent_layout "application" %>
```

However, when one of my users pages is rendered, this is present in the <head> element …

and this is also present when the users layout is rendered (in the <main> section) …

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-97ad5c0b00e27e03a2a434530385915aee55c42b8f0ae090c1a2abf4507ff7d8.css?body=1" />
```

I only want it present once.  What do I need to do to achieve this?  If it matters, this is the app/helpers/layout_helper.rb module I’m using

```
# Place this in app/helpers/layouts_helper.rb
module LayoutHelper
  def parent_layout(layout)
    @view_flow.set(:layout, output_buffer)
    output = render(:file => "layouts/#{layout}")
    self.output_buffer = ActionView::OutputBuffer.new(output)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For several layouts I just create an additional layout in the layouts folder and then at the end of the required controller action I do:

```
render layout: "user" # for your case it is "user"
```

So in fact you do not create nested layouts, but create separate layouts. You can move your current_user logic into the controller action to choose which layout to render. In order to make your layout views code DRY use partials.

Here is an example of how you could split your layouts:

```
<!-- application layout -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= render "layouts/head_section" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>

<!-- user layout -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= render "layouts/head_section" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "countries" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "users" %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
      </header>
      <main role="main">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <%= yield %>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- _head_section.html.erb -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Runtrax" %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Runtrax" %>">
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

# controller
def some_action
  ...
  render layout: (current_user.present? ? "user" : "application")
end
```

Though, if you want to utilize turbolinks in both layouts, you will need to consider including only nessesary js and css files in you application layout or manifest files, such as jquery, turbolinks, and other common functionality. And the rest should be included into your custom layouts, so your layouts will become as following:

```
<!-- application layout -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= render "layouts/head_section" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "none_users" %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>

<!-- user layout -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= render "layouts/head_section" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "countries" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "users" %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
      </header>
      <main role="main">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <%= yield %>
      </main>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>

<!-- _head_section.html.erb -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Runtrax" %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Runtrax" %>">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

In general, you want to minimize complexity in your layouts and avoid `if-else`s logic because such logic tends to become very confusing over time.

Comment: So what you're saying is take all of my application layout code and duplicate it in my user layout?

Comment: @Dave: I am saying that it is the way you build multiple layouts. As for duplication, multiple layouts imply that you have very different layouts that include different things. As I mentioned earlier, use partials to to avoid as much duplication as possible.

Comment: @Dave: I added to the answer an example of how you could split your layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the examples to explain what you're saying.  I don't like duplicating the application layout code in every layout that will inherit from application (in my app, there is more than just a users layout that inherits from teh application).  I would like to find a solution that solves the problem for the way I have the layouts, the reason being if I need to change something in the application layout, I only need ot make the change in one place instead of several.

Comment: @Dave: I am not sure what do you still mean by "duplicating the application layout code". Other than general html skeleton there should be no duplication, as it should be distributed among your partials (similar to the head_section partial). I remember myself couple years ago trying to do something similar to what you are trying now. BTW, if I am not mistaken there are ways to achieve it in Django, but it is another story.